# SharePoint Custom List View Permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got two custom list views in sharepoint with name "Region" and "Data".

"Region" items are as below
[image]

"Data" items are as below
[image]

The field "Region" in above "Data" custom list view is a lookup field to custom list view "Region"
The help I need doing is that I want to create three user groups with the name "Admin", "Part1" and "Part2" and I want to create the following user permissions to view the "Data" custom list view.
[image]

I'll be really grateful if someone can explain me in detail for how to do above as I don’t know much about SharePoint.  I am using SharePoint Server.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box approach will be to add 2 views on the page with different set of columns and set the audience targeting property of the web part to the particular user group.
When you edit a web part; in "Advanced" tab you will get "Target Audiences" option.

Answer (score 0):

Create three Sharepoint Group

- Admin
- Part1
- Part2

On **Data** List add new workflow with Sharepoint Designer, and add an **Impersonation step** with **Replace Permissions**, set start workflow on create and modify

Here a simple screenshot for Part1 group.
This workflow **replace permissions** on single item, consequently Part1 cannot edit/view item of Part2 and vice-versa, only admin can see/modify all.

This is based upon permissions you set on groups (Contribute, Read, Write, etc)

[image]